# Why is Julia in cyrillic regularly transcribed as Yulia in English?

Tags: transliteration

Julius Caesar's name is spelled with J both in Latin and in English. So is Julia the Elder. There are plenty of examples of Julia in English, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia

I think this applies to Jurij (Yurij) and other names that begins with Ju as well.

Why is Y often used when J is a very established spelling, which is used in e.g., German and Scandinavian languages?

Comment: Can you think of any English word where the letter J is pronounced like the letter Y?

Comment: Actually, Julius/Julia originally began with I in Latin; the distinction between the consonant J and the vowel I only evolved later.

Comment: @tchrist I struggled for a good few minutes trying to think of such a word, and then hallelujah, I found one!

Comment: Consider _why_ transliterating with ‘j’ is used in other Germanic languages, noting that English has a French ‘j’, _not_ a Germanic one.

Comment: @tchrist: Another one is *fjord*.  (Of course, that's because English adopted the Norwegian spelling as-is.)

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn: English normally pronounces `j` as /dʒ/, which is not quite the same as the French /ʒ/.  Still, the fact that German pronounces `j` as /j/ is irrelevant, as is the fact that Spanish pronounces `j` as /x/~/h/, and Mandarin Pinyin pronounces it as /tɕ/.

Comment: @Dan The English pronunciation has diverged from the French, but it’s still a result of Old French influence on Old English. My intended point though was that ‘’normal’ English pronunciation of ‘ju’ differs drastically from pretty much any rendering of ‘ю’ irrespective of language, while the ‘normal’ pronunciation of ‘ju’ in most other Germanic languages is relatively close to many (word initial) pronunciations of ‘ю’.

Comment: FWIW, the [scientific transliteration of the Russian Cyrillic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_transliteration_of_Cyrillic) does use "Julija" because the intended audience knows how that is supposed to sound. The same does the normal transcription from Russian and Ukrainian to Czech (Julija Tymošenko) for the same reasons.

Comment: It's funny how the whole confusion stems from the fact that when the name Iulius arrived in England via France they took the spelling and changed the pronunciation, while now that it is arriving via Russia they are taking the pronunciation but changing the spelling.

Comment: @tchrist the male name Jan, though whether you'd count a proper noun is debatable.  It's also pretty rare (in the UK, except in recent descendents of immigrants), but the example that sprang to mind spoke in RP.  Most other examples are loaned

Comment: While we're on it, why do Russians say 'Gandel' rather than 'Handel'?

Comment: @tchrist Yugoslavia used to be spelled with a 'J'.  There was once a Benny Hill skit where an ignorant 'newsreader' (Hill) stumbled over the word originally pronouncing it 'jug of saliva'.

Comment: @LeonConrad it's a case of fossilized spelling. At the time it was adopted Г could be G or soft G(like Dutch soft G if you've heard it, but transliterated as H in English) and German H sounded like a soft G to Russians. Soft G disappeared from most Russian dialects(and hard G from Ukranian). So the period pronunciation would have been G'(sounds like H to English speakers)andel.

Comment: FWIW Russian passport office transcribes the name as ‘Iuliia’, so Yulia is not your worst option.

Comment: @RomanShapovalov Well, since I and J wasn't separate letters in Rome that spelling makes much more sense than using Y.

Comment: @d-b OK, but that double ‘i’

Comment: @RomanShapovalov Look at the comment about scientific translation above, they use "Julija".

Comment: @RomanShapovalov: Because it's a letter-by-letter transliteration of `и` → `i` and `я` → `ia`.

Answer (score 27):

English speakers typically pronounce "Julius Caesar" and "Julia" with the sound /d͡ʒ/, like in the English word "jam".

It's true that in various European languages, including German and Scandinavian languages, J is an established spelling for the sound /j/ (like in the English word *year* or the German word *Jahr*). And English speakers may use that spelling and pronunciation in words or names that are spelled that way in the original language, such as someone named *Johann* in German or *Jan* in Swedish.

But that convention, although not completely unfamiliar to English speakers, is not the most common interpretation that English speakers tend to give to the letter J.

The convention of representing the sound /j/ as "y" is more familiar to English speakers. Since we are changing the spelling anyway when we transliterate from the Cyrillic alphabet, there's a tendency to use the option that makes it easier for English speakers to read the name with the right pronunciation. What German and Scandinavian languages do doesn't have much relevance in that context.

In fact, there are many [ways to romanize Cyrillic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Cyrillic) and you could see /j/ represented as J or even I in some systems rather than Y. Y is just a popular way of doing it.

Comment: Cyrillic transliterated using German conventions always looks Polish to me (all those Js and Ws).

Comment: @ColinFine Sowjets = flying pigs

Comment: French conventions are also found in some cases, especially classical music (Tchaikovsky), and seem to result in much longer names.

Answer (score 18):

There are basically three ways to deal with foreign names in English text.

1. Preserve the original **spelling** of the name.

   - If the name is originally written in the Latin alphabet, this can be done directly.
   - If the name is originally in a different script, the equivalent is to use a transliteration convention that preserves orthographical distinctions present in the source language.  For example, it's common to use `ك` → `k` and `ق` → `q` in names of Arabic origin, even though English speakers will pronounce both as /k/.
2. Preserve the original **pronunciation** of the name (to the extent allowed by English phonology).
3. **Translate** the name into an English language cognate.  For example, Spanish Juan → John, German Wilhelm → William, and Russian Екатерина   → Catherine.

The transcription Юлия → Yulia results from option #2: Preserving the pronunciation /ˈjʉlʲɪjə/, or rather, its English approximation /ˈjuːli.ə/.

English orthography is famously phonetically ambiguous (e.g., `a` is pronounced /eɪ/, /æ/, /ɑː/, or /ə/ in different contexts), and thus it's not always obvious how to represent a sequence of sounds with letters (or vice-versa).  But in general, English speakers have the expectation that `j` is pronounced /dʒ/, and `y` is pronounced /j/.  And conversely, the expected spelling of /j/ is `y`, and *not* `j`.  Hence, "**Y**ulia".

Sure, *some* people may be aware of the fact that `j` is pronounced /j/ in German (or Polish, Dutch, etc).  *But that's irrelevant.*  English speakers will read "Julia" as /ˈdʒuːli.ə/.  Even if you expect your readers to recognize the name as being different from the English "Julia", why expect them to pronounce `J` as German /j/ instead of as Spanish /x/~/h/, French /ʒ/, or Pinyin-Latinized Mandarin /tɕ/?  We're translating from Russian into English here, so there's no point in introducing a spelling convention from some arbitrary *third* language.

Answer (score 8):

In English, the letter “j” is (usually) /d͡ʒ/ and the fairly-common name “Julia” is pronounced /ˈd͡ʒuːli.ə/ even if the Julia in question is a historical figure that spoke Latin and would have pronounced the name /ˈi̯uː.li.a/ or /ˈju.li.a/ (depending on era, Classical vs. Ecclesiastical).

So for a modern person whose name is pronounced with the initial /j/ sound, “Julia” would be the wrong transliteration—“j” isn’t the (typical) letter that produces the /j/ sound in English. Instead, “y” (usually) does that. There are exceptions, typically from foreign names, *but*, those foreign names are 1. typically written in the Roman alphabet to begin with, so transliteration isn’t necessary, and 2. don’t have a conflict with an existing English name with a different pronunciation.

That said, Wikipedia lists at least a few notable figures with a /j/-initial “Julia” spelling.

Comment: Funnily enough, in Italian (which is relevant as it's the language we speak where once they spoke Latin) it evolved to /ˈd͡ʒu.li.a/, spelled Giulia.

Answer (score 4):

The same names, e.g., of biblical or Roman origin, are often pronounced differently in various languages - in a manner more suitable to the phonetic rules of that language. Thus, Russian or Bulgarian name *Yulia* corresponds to English or French *Julia*, but not pronounced the same. Official transcription rules used, e.g., for latinizing Cyrillic script for passports, then would require that the name is spelled *Yulia*.

Another factor is that the same letter may correspond to different sounds: e.g., German *Julia* is pronounced as *Yulia*

As similar examples one could mention:

- Jude/Judas - Yehuda (Hebrew/Yiddish) - Yuda/Iuda (russ.)
- Jacob/James(?) - Yakov - Iago (sp.)
- John - Jean (fr.) - Juan (sp., "Khuan") - Ivan (rus.) - Johan (germ.)
- Joan - Jeanne (fr) - Yoanna/Yana (rus.)
- Joseph - Iosif (rus.) - Josef (germ.) - Jose (sp.)

Comment: Jeanne etc. is Jane or Joan in English, not Anne!

Comment: @KateBunting all of them trace to the same Greek name - just like *Yoanna/Anna* in Russian.

Comment: @KateBunting though, upon reflection - Anna could also originate from Hanna.

Comment: According to the _Oxford Dictionary of English Christian Names_ Anne derives from the Hebrew Hannah, while Jane/Joan are feminine forms of John, from the Hebrew Johanan.

Comment: @KateBunting perhaps, but in Slavic languages the distinction is clearly blurred: *Yoanna* vs. *Anna*, *Ioann Krestitel* = *John the Baptist*

Comment: Clearly? My researches seem to indicate that Yana/Yoanna is a different name from Anna.

Comment: @KateBunting there is proliferation of names - every time one pronounces or spells a name differently, it gives rise to a new name. What is your point exactly - you want me to remove this example? Otherwise, we violate SE policy by engaging in a lengthy discussion in comments.

Comment: I was merely pointing out that Anne and its _variants_ are a different name from Jane and its variants., in all languages.

Comment: Judas in Russian is clearly not Yuda if we go the phonetical route, but rather Iuda.

Comment: @Lodinn I think both Иуда and Йуда are possible - certainly in spoken speech. The New Testament character is more likely to be pronounced as Иуда by more literate public, but I heard the other pronunciation on many occasions. There are also last names like Юдин which trace to the same Hebrew name (though a different biblical character) - usually pronounced as Йегуда in Russian, where *h* is often hardened to *г*, but the original pronunciation is actually closer to Йуда (and this is how it is pronounced in Modern Hebrew.)

Comment: Most interesting. I am not a church-goer but I also genuinely struggle to remember whether I even ever heard the "Йуда" variant in spoken speech. After some consideration, it seems like a possible reduction in some dialects, but still strikes me as decidedly nonstandard. Юдин is definitely fair game here, and I'd say Йегуда is a bit more standard than Иегуда indeed, but I have heard both. It would seem old Hebrew names in modern Russian (and many others) are truly eclectic, and the same phonemes have evolved differently in different names.

Comment: I have heard "Йуда" from people who grew up in villages in Volga region. If I paid attention to it at the time, it was precisely because it had struck me as unusual. I mention now both versions in my answer.

Comment: Iago, not Tiago. Tiago is rebracketed.

Comment: @AakashM Good point. Thanks.